# Redirecting First Page to paginated version

Tags: seo, pagination

A theory question here,

If I've got a paginated section on my website and the URL is

```
website.com/news
```

this page has multiple pages.

Should I automatically redirect visitors on `/news` to `/news/page/1`

If i leave it as both `/news` and `/news/page/1` this will be duplicated content according to Google. Or is Google smart enough to tell if its the first page?

Whats the best practice to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tag yout pages correctly so that Google understands this is paginated content and won't penalize you for duplicate content.

Tag your pagination links with rel="next", and rel="prev", then rel="canonical" each paginated page to the full non-paginated version. For real users of course you do not redirect to non-paginated content ever.

If you do this Google will treat each paginated page as if it were one giant non-paginated page.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2012/03/video-about-pagination-with-relnext-and.html

Comment: So if my pagination is Prev 1 2 3 [4] 5 6 Next, will google see /news as duplicate content as /news/page/1 as they ahve different urls

Comment: No. So /news/page/1 is rel=canonical to /news. So you are telling Google that these two pages are the same. Normally since the pages are not mostly the same Google would ignore and/or penalize you for canonicaling to a page which is very different. But you fix that by making all the paginated pages link together though rel=next and rel=prev. E.g. first google will glue together all the paginated pages through next/prev to create on mega page, then compare that to your non paginated page and see that its very similar content and allow the rel=canonical.

Comment: To google there will be only one virtual page in the index - the non-paginated page. To users there will be all the paginated pages.